# Controller View not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel Framework. it is showing error when I run the page with the controller I created.
The routes can detect the Controller and its views but it just won't show.

**Routes:**

[image]

**Error:**

[image]

Product Controller index():

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::latest()->paginate(5);

    return view('products.index',compact('products'))
        ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

Comment: Hello, please show the code of the controller index method, and the directory where you have stored the view.

Comment: Is index.blade.php available inside products folder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is from a controller method that's supposed to return a view. It means the view file is not found. using `view('product.index')` indicates that you're telling laravel to look for an `index.blade.php` file in `/resources/views/products` directory and it throws that error if the file is not found

Comment: Hi. Thank you. Didn't realize that the /product folder is not inside the views.